# How to set element as active when either of the sublink routes are active angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following code snippet for generating bootstrap `nav-taps` with an embedded dropdown list:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="pull-right">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> More <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/profile/settings']">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/profile/billing']">Billing</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-right" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/profile/feature1']">Feature1</a></li>
      <li class="pull-right" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/profile/feature2']">Feature2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This works fine for the normal tabs, but I can't figure out how to make the dropdown list active when either of the embedded links are active. I tried:

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> More <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

but it doesn't seem to solve anything, anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm dumb and attempted putting the `[routerLinkActive]` on the `<a>` element instead of `<li>`. Once I put it on the top most `li` it worked like a charm!

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="pull-right" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> More <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/profile/settings']">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/profile/billing']">Billing</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="pull-right" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/profile/feature1']">Feature1</a></li>
  <li class="pull-right" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/profile/feature2']">Feature2</a></li>
</ul>
```